# Npm Install straight from package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have a simple question that i cant seem to find the answer for. I cloned a git repo to my local machine.

When attempting to start node, I receive an error because i don't have the required npm dependencies installed. However, they are located in the packages.json file that was cloned.

I was wondering if there was a simple way to install the dependencies located in that file, without having to npm install for every individual package.

Comment: `npm install` without arguments installs all modules in package.json.

Comment: @Phix I get errors when i try that....npm WARN Invalid version: "0.1"
npm WARN server No description
npm WARN server No repository field.
npm WARN server No README data
npm WARN server No license field

Comment: @Hysii Usually, warrnings are not equivalent to errors. Don't be afraid of warnings though - but it would be a better idea if you could provide a link to the package.json, if you're experiencing issues / errors while npm install.

Comment: Post your package.json file here. It'll be faster than assuming what it looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, at this point i just installed individual packages. I was pretty sure 'npm install' installed all dependencies, so thanks for confirming my preconceived assumption

Answer (score 10):

Within the directory of the `package.json` file, just run `npm install`. It will read `package.json` and install all dependencies. If you want to limit it to only non-dev dependencies, use `npm install --only=production`.